# Каким способом можно оформить данный элемент, чтобы он был адаптивным?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите каким образом создать данный элемент, чтобы он был адаптивен? Первое как пробовал его оформить это путем трансформа дива и псевдокласс бефо, однако из за абсолютного позиционирования идут разлеты между формой и этим так называемым бордером.

---

[image: скрин]

Comment: А где код? Что бы  дать внятный  ответ, надо иметь представления, как он был реализован...

Comment: А форма position:absolute ?

Comment: Да реализован был через абсолют

Comment: Кода нет, так как не считаю его правильным, его не просто нужно править а написать нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#form{
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
}
#form input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
#form:before{
    content: '';
    width: 30px;
    height: 103%;
    background-color: darkred;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: -6px;
    transform: skewX(15deg) rotate(15deg);
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;width:10%;height:200px;background-color:gray"></div>
<div style="float:left;width:90%;height:200px;background-color:lightgray">
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="text"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо помог)